# Short term and long term effect of delaying protein intake after workout

Tags: diet, post-workout

Today, after a high intensity leg workout, I had to wait 45 minutes before I could take in any food. Usually, I go with a fish/meat dinner, or simply a protein shake.

I was wondering, how does this affect my restitution in the short term? Will my workout have a diminished effect because I didn't take in protein straight after finishing?

Also, what would be the long term effect if I consistently didn't take in protein until an hour (give or take) after finishing a weightlifting workout?

And for perspective, what if I had to wait 4 hours every time?

Specifically, **how would my muscles cope with longer periods (consistently) of no protein intake after a heavy workout?**

The regular advice is "protein shake ASAP after workout", but I'm wondering where this is coming from.

Assume regular dieting beforehand. Nothing protein heavy. Just a bog standard bread breakfast and bread/fruit lunch.

Comment: related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21/effect-of-protein-intake-on-muscle-recovery?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The regular advice is "protein shake ASAP after workout", but I'm
>   wondering where this is coming from.

As a guy who has a financial interest in the supplement industry, I can tell you where you're getting that message from: supplement manufactures and retailers. The idea is to make you think that unless you consume a given product you won't be maximizing your "gains".

> And for perspective, what if I had to wait 4 hours every time?
>
> Specifically, how would my muscles cope with longer periods
>   (consistently) of no protein intake after a heavy workout?

You probably have enough protein in your blood at that point. Follow my math on this. With the exception of whey, which is rather fast-absorbed, [most natural sources of protein take somewhere in the neighborhood of 3-7 hours to be broken down](http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/nutrition/what-are-good-sources-of-protein-speed-of-digestion-part-2.html/), so protein is slowly being released from your gut, broken into amino acids, and sent into your blood.

So if you had ham and eggs at 6 in the morning, even by noon (6 hours later) you still have amino acids moving around in your blood. If you slammed a whey shake at 10 in the morning, you have *a lot* of amino acids rushing around come noon time.

The general idea for "eat protein every few hours" is to have a steady state of amino acids rushing around through your blood since repair work is done slowly over a period of hours and days.

**Directly answering your question:**

You probably are not going long periods without protein. Provided you have a balanced diet, enough protein, and eat throughout the day (don't sweat the details on that part), you've got amino acids floating around able to keep up.

I'm a big believer in supplements, but they're not magic beans, and I don't like how the marketing spin makes people think that if they don't use a tub of powder every day they'll shrivel up to a 120lb weakling.

Comment: Is it safe to assume then, that if I've consumed a good deal of protein a couple hours before training, that I'll still reap similar benefits when the workout is over?

Comment: @Aleksander, yes, especially if you ate real food that's slow to digest. Most proteins fall into this category *except* for whey.

Comment: Ah, so a protein shake (which is usually whey) is indeed best served right after the workout?

Comment: @Aleksander yes. Again I wouldn't sweat the timing so much as the overall daily intake, real food minimizing the timing impact a lot because of its slow release.

Answer (score 4):

If you are weight lifting to build muscle strength, according to a 2012 study, "Protein timing and its effects on muscular hypertrophy and strength in individuals engaged in weight-training," published in the [Journal of the International Society of Sports Nutrition](http://www.jissn.com/content/9/1/54), timing and type of protein makes a difference in MPS: Maximal Protein Synthesis.

> In general, protein supplementation pre- and post-workout increases physical performance, training session recovery, lean body mass, muscle hypertrophy, and strength.

If you don't have time to eat, at least consider **drinking milk**.

- **Timing**

  The study looks at pre and post workout protein intake.

  > These data show that there is a limited time window within which to induce protein synthesis before a refractory period begins. With this in mind, an ideal protein supplement after resistance exercise should contain whey protein, as this will rapidly digest and initiate MPS, and provide 3–4 g of leucine per serving, which is instrumental in promoting maximal MPS.
  >
  > Once a protein has been consumed by an individual, anabolism is increased for about three hours postprandial with a peak at about 45–90 minutes [14]. After about three hours postprandial, MPS drops back to baseline even though serum amino acid levels remain elevated
- **Post Workout:**

  > An ideal supplement following resistance exercise should contain whey protein that provides at least 3 g of leucine per serving.
  >
  > ..studies using protein sources with a carbohydrate source tended to increase LBM more than did a protein source alone.

  - **Pre Workout**

  > In contrast, the consumption of essential amino acids and dextrose appears to be most effective at evoking protein synthesis prior to rather than following resistance exercise.
- **Type of Protein:**

  Whey protein showed increases in strength.  Casein did not. (Milk contains both whey and casein.)

  > **fat-free milk post-workout was effective in promoting increases in lean body mass, strength, muscle hypertrophy and decreases in body fat**
  >
  > 3–4 g of leucine needed to promote maximal MPS
- **Regarding addition of carbohydrate with protein ingestion:**

  > A combination of a fast-acting carbohydrate source such as maltodextrin or glucose should be consumed with the protein source, as leucine cannot modulate protein synthesis as effectively without the presence of insulin [27,28] and studies using protein sources with a carbohydrate source tended to increase LBM more than did a protein source alone [33,37-41]. Such a supplement would be ideal for increasing muscle protein synthesis, resulting in increased muscle hypertrophy and strength.