# When does maximum muscle repair and growth take place after a strength workout?

Tags: strength, muscle-mass, muscle-recovery

Every strength routine includes rest days between workouts, so that the natural processes of tissue repair and muscle growth are allowed.

I guess this process of repair and growth happens mostly between the first and maybe the fourth day after a strength workout. I am curious about any study that quantifies the amount of muscle tissue added as a function of time after a strength workout. Is there any such study?

Comment: This [q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19631/short-term-and-long-term-effect-of-delaying-protein-intake-after-workout/19635#19635) does not really answer your question but it includes a link to a study about protein supplementation in regards to timing of maximal protein synthesis and its effects on muscular hypertrophy,  strength, and training session recovery which may be of some help to you.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy +1, you nail it! That is what I want to know, but I can't ask it directly, the question would be closed by moderators because it is about nutrition... Otherwise my real question would have been "I take between two and four days rest between strength workouts, and I don't want to maintain a high protein intake during all that time, otherwise I will become merely fat. When should I rise my protein intake in order to maximize its efficiency?" - However, the q/a you suggest still doesn't have the answer. I want to know in which of my 2~4 days rest should I eat more protein.

Answer (score 4):

Coming up with a single function for muscle tissue repair with respect to time is literally impossible. Each individual is far too different for any *one* function to represent us all. It's the whole "one size does NOT fit all" problem that holds for pretty much any physiological issue.

That said, there is a [study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22330017) that suggests that ingesting protein just before sleep causes a rapid rise in circulating amino acids during sleep. Perhaps it is less a function of time, and more a function of your body's state of rest?

Comment: +1, quite close to what I am interested in, when I ask this question.