# Can i take shower immediately after taking whey protein?

Tags: post-workout, whey

Can i take shower immediately after taking whey protein? Some of my friends suggested after workout(Taking whey) is not good for me. They said protein will not absorb as much. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand the up-vote here.

Comment: @rrirower - I don't understand the tendency to VTC as off topic and then answer the question.

Comment: @JohnP Exactly!  And, that's one of the reasons for my recent [meta post](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/686/proposal-opinion-based-answers).  There's got to be something we can do to discourage that.

Comment: K enough carry on with your work :)

Comment: Are you interpreting the question correctly? I think OP is asking about timing of protein post-workout. I.e. should he shower or supplement protein first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showering does not affect the bodies absorption of protein. Timing of protein is not that important for majority of people:

[How Much Protein Do I Need To Build Mass?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31626/how-much-protein-do-i-need-to-build-mass/31627#31627)

[Short term and long term effect of delaying protein intake after workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19631/short-term-and-long-term-effect-of-delaying-protein-intake-after-workout)